# how to make timer_create and timer_delete multi-thread proof

Tags: c++, pthreads, posix

I am stuck in a peculiar situation where I call timer_create from one thread and call the timer_delete from another thread. But I cant seem to get it work as it ends up in a deadlock:

I cannot figure out how to make it thread safe, should I use mutexes? or should I use some other way to avoid deadlocks?

my code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "pthread.h"



typedef struct 
{
    struct sigevent     tmrSigEvt;
    timer_t             tmr;
}TMR_DATA_T;

int a = 10;
int b = 20;
int c = 0;


TMR_DATA_T tmrDataArray[5] = { 0 };

void TimerCallback( union sigval timer_data )
{
    std::cout<<"am i here\n";
    c = a + b;
}

int32_t CreateTimer( int32_t timerId, const uint32_t msPeriod )
{
    int32_t ret = -1;

    uint8_t slot = timerId;
    timer_t *tmrPtr = &tmrDataArray[slot].tmr;
    struct itimerspec period;
    uint32_t tmpPeriod;

    tmrDataArray[slot].tmrSigEvt.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    tmrDataArray[slot].tmrSigEvt.sigev_notify_function = TimerCallback;
    tmrDataArray[slot].tmrSigEvt.sigev_signo = timerId;
    tmrDataArray[slot].tmrSigEvt.sigev_value.sival_ptr = ( void* )&tmrDataArray[slot];
    tmrDataArray[slot].tmrSigEvt.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

    ret = timer_create( /*CLOCK_REALTIME*/ CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tmrDataArray[slot].tmrSigEvt, tmrPtr );
    std::cout<<"----------------DO I COME HERE AFTER CREATING THE TIMER---------\n";


    tmpPeriod = msPeriod % 1000;    // remainder or period less than 1sec
    period.it_value.tv_nsec = ( long )( tmpPeriod * 1000000 );        // nano-seconds
    period.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;                                // non-repeating timer
    period.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
    ret = timer_settime( *tmrPtr, 0, &period, NULL );

    return ret;

}


int32_t DeleteTimer( int32_t timerId )
{
    int32_t ret = -1;
    if ( NULL != tmrDataArray[timerId].tmr )
    {
        ret = timer_delete( tmrDataArray[timerId].tmr );
         std::cout<<"Deleting the timer inside ------\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"failed to delete the timer\n";
    }
    return ret;
}




void *Create_Timer_thread1( void *ptr )
{
    std::cout<<"Creating a timer\n";
    CreateTimer( 2, 100 );
    std::cout<<"done creating a timer\n";
    return NULL;
}


void *Delete_Timer_thread2( void *ptr )
{
    std::cout<<"second thread deleting a timer\n";
    DeleteTimer(2);
    return NULL;
}




int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    int  iret1, iret2;

    iret1 = pthread_create( &thread1, NULL, Create_Timer_thread1, NULL);
    std::cout<<"creating the second thread\n";

    iret2 = pthread_create( &thread2, NULL, Delete_Timer_thread2, NULL);


    pthread_join( thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join( thread2, NULL); 

    std::cout<<"the value of c is: "<<c<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @pilcrow sometimes I end up with a deadlock where I get stuck at a timer_create() function and it never moves on

Comment: the statement ` ----------------DO I COME HERE AFTER CREATING THE TIMER---------` does not print out. meaning I do not come out of the timer_create function

Comment: Please show us, in an edit to your question, exactly the output you see when running, and whether there's an exit code for the program.  Then tell us the output you expected to see.  At a glance, I don't think you deadlock — I think `main` causes your program to exit before you hit any of your race conditions/undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You need to synchronize threads when accessing and manipulating any global data. In you case `c` and `tmrDataArray`. There are multiple ways to achieve that. I would suggest using mutex whenever you are accesing `tmrDataArray` and for simple data types as `c` I would advise you to look into atomic variables.